# iPhone iWebDriver and Selenium grid returning org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the request For input string: "(null)"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am trying to run Selenium grid with actual devices. My set up (kind of) works when I use android phones but when I use an iPhone it gives me the following error message

```
"Error forwarding the request For input string: "(null)"
```

So my question boils down to:

1. How do you set up iPhone WebDriver with Selenium Grid2?

What I did so far:

Grid Set up:

Setting up selenium Grid

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role hub
```

Setting up iPhone node

Go to Settings > iWebDriver

Port: 3001

Grid : localhost ip Address and Port: 4444

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role webdriver -host [phone Host] -port 3001 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iPhone,platform=MAC
```

I then run a junit test with the following

```
 public void testIphoneDriver() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub") , capability);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");   }
```

I am then given an error "Error forwarding the request For input string: "(null)" 
Strangely enough if I connect to the device directly (replacing localhost:4444 with the iPhone IP address) it works fine.

Below is the stack trace

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request For input string: "(null)"
>   Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 15:53:30'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:111)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
>       at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>       at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: In your iPhone under Settings->Webdriver you just need to mention the hub port and the Hub IP address. Nothing more in those fields.

Answer (score 0):

We have provided some documentation on how to configure the connectivity and the Grid for the iPhone driver on the relevant wiki page for the Selenium project http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver

You might also test connectivity exists between your tests and the hub; and the hub and the iphone with webdriver running on it; using telnet or even a web browser to connect to the respective URLs e.g. to

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

if you're using a web browser on your machine that'll run the tests.

I hope that's sufficient to enable you and people in a similar predicament to get their tests working. Thanks for a detailed description of what you've done.